# Recyclerview with different cards and different data sources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview and I have at least 3 types of cards with different properties. Logic for switching cards layout is a non issue, but I am wondering what is the best way for me to grab the data.

I guess I can add different webservice data to a list or I can add them to an array where one column is key for type of ws.

I just need some pointers about how other people would do it. My recyclerview today has 3 cards layouts and the view resides inside a fragment. I do the WS calls in the main activity.

I at first wanted to use classes but some cards will use many properties and some few. Like a card for watch widget dosent need data. Current weather needs 3 properties and weather forecast maybe 15. I am thinking maybe I should pass an array that references type of card and then grab the data (as a key)? If I use classes I would have to make very generic names and not all cards would use all of them (not that this is hard to do, but Im thinking it looks silly).

In theory I guess looking at google now shows the different types of cards with different properties from different sources. How would you guys arrange the dataset for such usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use a parent class and extend from that the classes for every different type of card. Check the `viewType` in your `ViewHolder` and cast the item to the one that represents.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I think maybe that's a good way to solve it. I see many people are passing multiple arrays but I think that will make potential inconsitencies. Extending classes is what I do with the viewholders already for the different views. I think it's a viable way that also means I dont have to give generic names like property1, property2 etc :-P Then I can give them proper names like temperature, humidity for some cards while others have maybe pm25, pm10 etc. :-)

Thank you again!